# Parse CSV file with diffrent header names and different location

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I having a problem understanding how to parse a CSV file which can contain a **different header (column) name**. In addition, the column name can be location each time in a **different column**.

What is the best approach?
How can i make it as generic as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine NewtonsoftJson (for parse csv) and Automapper (for map object with different fields)